# Simpler check if a cell was edited and a certain value inserted (Google spreadsheet script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to check if the cell I'm interested in has been edited and changed to a certain value. Within `function onEdit(event)` I'm currently checking if the sheet, column, row and cell content are correct:

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var range_active = event.source.getActiveRange();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  var sheet_template = ss.getSheetByName("Template");

  var cell_test = sheet_template.getRange("B2");

  if(ss.getActiveSheet().getName() == "Template") {

    if(
        range_active.getColumn() == 2
        && range_active.getRow() == 2
        && cell_test.getValue() == "A"
      )
    {
        //  Do something here
    }
  }
}
```

So there are 4 checks here. Is there a simpler way to checking if my cell (here B2) has been edited and its value changed to "A"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function cellB2EqualToA(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var range = e.source.getActiveRange();
  var rangeA1 = range.getA1Notation();
  var value = sheet.getRange(rangeA1).getValue();

  if(value != 'A' && rangeA1 != 'B2'){
    return;
  }else{
    //do what you need to do
  };
}
```